# Increase reputation when a link contributes to the Q&A discussion

Tags: feature-request, reputation, hyperlinks

People often post links within their answers and comments. When those links contribute to the discussion, the profile associated with the site hosting the link could earn some reputation.

For example, I could earn some reputation :) since my website is cited several times on stackoverflow.com, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=www.monperrus.net

With proper stabilization mechanisms (site verification, no self-links, etc.), this could be a way to build a stackoverflow-based internet-wide Q&A reputation.

Comment: Your reputation should be based on your actions on the site; Not the rest of the internet. How do we know that you are indeed the one creating the content on your site? I don't mean to sound mean... Just giving an example..

Comment: Apart from being a terribly bad idea, how is this going to work with multiple people claiming ownership of a URL? *Lot's* of sites are edited by multiple people, this is going to be a nightmare just to manage ownership claims and disputes.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions! I still think that clever rules and "The Crowd" could recognize the inner value of links.

Answer (score 14):

Err, I don't think it's a good idea.

Basically you're asking to get reputation because your site is being shared (i.e. promoted) on the site. This will only encourage people to spam the answers with their own site, certainly something that we don't want to do and that mods across the network are trying to contrast.

It encourages the wrong thing. Not to mention that it's already explicitly forbidden [in the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion):

> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. [...]

Comment: And even if there were some verification in place to prevent people from unfairly gaining rep through links, we generally consider links of secondary importance. We prefer self-contained answers and even actively remove link-only answers. Links are welcome, but I see no reason to actively promote them.

Comment: @Bart True. If links help improve the answer, great, but they shouldn't be the center of the answer.